# Carbon Date Being Saved as String in Database

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to seed some data using Factories.  One of the fields I'm trying to seed is a date field -- and I do so with the following code in my factory:

```
return [
    ...
    'date' => Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(1, 365))->startOfDay()
];
```

The problem is, this is getting saved in the database as a string -- which means that I CANNOT do the following in my blade templates:  `{{ $transaction->date->format('M, d Y') }}`,

When I try that, I get the following error message:  `Call to a member function format() on string`.

Just as a test, I tried in my blade template the same exact code, just switching out `created_at` for `date` - and it works as I want.  I.e., this works:   `{{ $transaction->created_at->format('M, d Y') }}`.

In case it matters, the `created_at` field is created using `$table->timestamps()` in my migration file whereas the `date` field is created as follows:  `$table->date('date');`.

Any idea what I need to do in order to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: That did it -- thanks.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.  Either way, again thanks :).

Comment: Converted to an answer   I initially didn't post as an answer due to my unfamiliarity with Factories and how they work, but since they're tied to a Model, it should work the same. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides a method to "cast" certain Model attributes to specific datatypes, including strings, integers, dates, etc. Since Carbon is built in to Laravel, specifying the `date` type auto-converts Model attributes to a Carbon instance. All you need to do is provide that logic to your model:

```php
class Transaction extends Model {
  protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'date'
  ];
  ...
}
```

Now, when you retrieve a `Transaction` model record, the `date` attribute will automatically be a `Carbon` instance:

```php
$transaction = Transaction::first();
dd($transaction->date, get_class($transaction->date));
// ^ Carbon\Carbon @1646769789^ {#4514 ... }, `Carbon\Carbon`
```

Now, you can perform Carbon logic, simply by chaining:

```php
{{ $transaction->date->format('Y-m-d') }}
// `2022-03-08`
```

More casting types are available, and you can specify multiple attribute casts by simply adding them as key/value pairs to the `$casts` array. Full documentation is here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Thanks -- very nice and detailed explanation :-).